# I cannot create directories/folders in Android Studio and Flutter, only packages

Tags: android-studio, flutter

As you can see here, the option to create new directories doesn't exist, i can only add new packages.

What I want to do though is create a folder structure like

```
>Lib
>>Pages
>>>Startpage
>>>Loginpage
>>Helpers
>>>Networkhelper
>>>>Requesthelper
>>>Storagehelper
etc...
```

which i can't do with packages as i cannot put packages into empty packages and stuff

[image]

this worked before, however now when i created a new project, the same way i always did, it didn't work. any ideas on what i can do/what went wrong?

Comment: They should basically be the same, but why not making the folder structure using the file manager instead of the android studio's project view?

Comment: @KhashayarMotarjemi that's what i've been doing however i am more worried that something is fundamentally broken in the project and the missing directory option is just a symptom of a larger issue

Comment: Actually I checked now and there isn't a directory option for me either so I don't think that's a problem and I guess package does exactly the same here.

Comment: @KhashayarMotarjemi huh i wonder why it worked before, but thank you still!

Answer (score 23):

For some reason, lib directory is marked as source root. Its actually doesn't make difference wether shown as package or folder. Its the same thing. But if you want to change it, unmark it.

in your project tree:

project_name -> lib:

- right click
- mark directory as
- unmark as source root

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrHOJ.png)

Hope it help.

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you.

Comment: i've edited it, but i dont really understand deeply, so if someone want to explain more, go ahead.

Comment: mine was unmarked. That is not the cause

Answer (score 0):

just open VS CODE and create the desired folder
it should work that way

Comment: The question pertains to Android Studio - not VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

**Initial Situation:**
On Android Studio you can only add a "Package", not a Directory.
[image]

**SOLUTION**

**Step # 1:** Open the Project Structure window.

Either press Command+; or go through *File > Project Structure*:

[image]

Then you should see something like this:
[image]

**Step 2:** Remove the lib folder from the the project's sources root:

1. Click on "*Modules*" on the left panel.
2. Click on the lib folder.
3. Unmark "*Sources*" right on top of it (the lib folder will change its color from blue to gray).
4. Press the "OK" button on the bottom right to apply the changes.

[image]

**Final Situation:**

Now you can add a Directory.
[image]